# How do you use JPA objects with GWT in a different project?

Tags: gwt, jpa

I'm new to GWT, and I'm setting up a project to hold the UI portion of a complicated application.  The JPA data objects are defined in a separate project using MyBatis generated POJOs.  Once I manually modify the JPA objects to include 'implements Serializable' (this is a separate problem I need to solve), the gwtc step in the build process can't continue because it needs the source code for the JPA object, but can't find them.

I've created the 'core' project's jar files so that it includes the source .java files, but this didn't work.  I've tried adding a classpath element to the gwtc ant java call.

How can I make my UI project compile while keeping the JPA objects defined in a separate project?

Errors:

```
Buildfile: /Users/user/source/user_interface/build.xml

libs:

javac:

gwtc:
     [java] Compiling module org.mysite.ui
     [java]    Validating newly compiled units
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/user/source/user_interface/src/org/mysite/ui/client/MyService.java'
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 21: No source code is available for type org.mysite.core.model.Person; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/user/source/user_interface/src/org/mysite/ui/client/MyServiceAsync.java'
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 19: No source code is available for type org.mysite.core.model.Person; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/user/source/user_interface/src/org/mysite/ui/client/presenter/MainTabPresenter.java'
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 75: No source code is available for type org.mysite.core.model.Person; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [java]    Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/Users/user/source/user_interface/src/org/mysite/ui/client/MyApp.java
     [java]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.mysite.ui.client.MyService'
     [java]          Rebinding org.mysite.ui.client.MyService
     [java]             Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.user.rebind.ui.ImageBundleGenerator'/>
     [java]                [ERROR] Unable to find type 'org.mysite.ui.client.MyService'
     [java]                   [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
     [java]                   [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
     [java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/user/source/user_interface/src/org/mysite/ui/client/MyApp.java'
     [java]       [ERROR] Line 23:  Failed to resolve 'org.mysite.ui.client.MyService' via deferred binding
     [java]    [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors

BUILD FAILED
/Users/user/source/user_interface/build.xml:39: Java returned: 1

Total time: 26 seconds
```

Ant gwtc target:

```
  <target name="gwtc" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript (production mode)">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <pathelement location="../core/src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
      </classpath>
      <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
      <arg line="-war"/>
      <arg value="web"/>
      <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
      <arg line="${gwt.args}"/>
      <arg value="org.mysite.ui.MyApp"/>
    </java>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT has always had this problem.

The approach I have taken in the past is to make a .gwt.xml module in the other JAR including the JPA POJOs and putting the JPA annotation classes in an "emul" javax.persistence folder. This won't work w/ many providers that use lazy fetching of course, so Gilead (as mentioned in another answer here) will be needed.

Another way is to make copies of the JPA objects and just Dozer them before sending across RPC

Luckily, GWT 2.1 has solved this problem. Use [Entity proxies](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) and request factories. It works well.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to get the .gwt.xml to compile in the data project and then integrate with the web project?  This seems like an ideal solution for my situation.

Comment: So, I added the gwt.xml to the data project, built the jar, copied it to the other project, and added an 'inherit' in the web project.  Since it's on the classpath, gwt finds the DataModel.gwt.xml file, and knows about the classes.  I'm getting really close with this solution!

Comment: I moved the gwt.xml to the web project, but in the same java package as the data folders in the data project.  I released the jar for the data project as separate class and source jars.  GWT checks the classpath for the packages defined by the gwt.xml and compiles them in the web project.  Works like stink.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, been out of pocket. First, if you want to include another JAR'd module in a production environment, make sure the .java files for all client source are in there. Don't confuse GWT's dev mode w/ a production deployment. Are you having other problems?

Comment: Nope - I create two jars - one with classes, and one with source files only.  It's working great!

Answer (score 2):

1. Either use the new GWT 2.1 [RequestFactory / EntityPro](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/DevGuideRequestFactory.html)xy approach, or
2. Better, ditch the JPA and use [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) or [Twig](http://code.google.com/p/twig-persist/).

We use Objectify, because JPA is not a good fit for Datastore. JPA was created with SQL-based relational databases in mind, while GAE Datastore is an entirely different thing.

Google ported JPA layer to Datastore to lure in developers, pretending that Datastore is just a plain old SQL relational database. This later blows up in their faces once projects grow big.

You really need to understand the Datastore tradeoffs if you want to use AppEngine. JPA is not making you a favor here.

Comment: EntityProxy is very new and I have not used it yet, but probably will soon as I have always planned on writing a generator for this exact purpose.  Your comment about ditching JPA for Objectify is a good idea if you plan on using GAE, but if you are using a SQL-based database in conjunction with a J2EE server like Glassfish or JBoss then sticking with JPA and EntityProxy will be a better approach.  This also assumes that you are using GWT-RPC.  I have written a generator similar to EntityProxy but for JSON communication.

Comment: The JPA exists, and is being used, so switching isn't an option at this point.  EntityProxy seems to want me to annotate the generated classes.  Again, not using the simple data classes externally generated that I want to use client-side.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet if you want to serialize POJOs to GWT is to use Gilead http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/

All you have to do on your POJO is extend LightEntity and implement Serializable

The tutorial is pretty straight forward in how to set up the RPC.